# Looping through list of data frames and add a new column based on another data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a couple of data frames:

```
df1: 
c1  (a,b,c) c2 (1,2,5) 

df2:

c1 (d,e,f)  c2 (4,7,10)
```

Another dataframe `df3 c1: (1,3,7,9,11)` (this will always be sorted)

I need a new column in `df1` and `df2` (df1,2 name would be stored in a loop variable) which should be the smallest element present in `df3` that is greater than / equal to the corresponding `c2` value in `df1`, `df2`.

E.g., for `df1`, `c3` would be (1,3,7)

1. How do I add a new column when the data frame name is a variable?
2. Get a vectorised version of `min(which df3$c1>= df1$c2)`?

I believe R isn't able to properly vectorise the second formula as it has two arrays of varying lengths.

Comment: Please provide your data with valid R syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c1=letters[1:3], c2=c(1,2,5), stringsAsFactors=F)
df2 <- data.frame(c1=letters[4:6],c2=c(4,7,10), stringsAsFactors=F)
df3 <- data.frame(c1=c(1,3,7,9,11))


df1$newCol <- apply(Vectorize(function(x) x>=df1$c2)(df3$c1),1, function(i) min(df3$c1[i]))

 df1
 #   c1 c2 newCol
 # 1  a  1      1
 # 2  b  2      3
 # 3  c  5      7


df2$newCol <- apply(Vectorize(function(x) x>=df2$c2)(df3$c1),1, function(i) min(df3$c1[i]))
```

If `df1` is stored in a variable

```
x <- "df1"

apply(Vectorize(function(y) y>= get(x)$c2)(df3$c1), 1, function(i) min(df3$c1[i]))
#[1] 1 3 7
```

#### Update

```
assign(x, `[[<-`(get(x), 'c3', value=apply(Vectorize(function(y) y>= get(x)$c2)(df3$c1), 1, function(i) min(df3$c1[i]))))
get(x)
#  c1 c2 c3
# 1  a  1  1
# 2  b  2  3
# 3  c  5  7
```